# Mysql REGEXP parts of string in a given string regardless of their position

Tags: mysql, regex

Need quick help with regular expression. Any regex experts out there who can look into this for me?

I basically want to write a regex in SQL that can help find parts of string in a given string regardless of their position. example below:

This works:

```
select 'I am sql' regexp '(.*I) (.*am)';
```

This doesn't work

```
select 'I am sql' regexp '(.*am)(.*I)';
```

Thanks

Comment: Provide some sample data and expected output.

Comment: select 'I am sql' regexp '(.*am)(.*I)';   I just want dis one to return true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
regexp '(I.*am)|(am.*I)';
```

If you want word boundaries, too, then

```
regexp '([[:<:]]I[[:>:]].*[[:<:]am[[:>:]])|([[:<:]am[[:>:]].*[[:<:]I[[:>:]])';
```